# Can't use Sybase.AdoNet.AseClient.dll in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ado.net, database-connection, sap-ase

I was installed Sybase.AdoNet.AseClient.dll from Nuget and when i try to use it, it is throwing error as there is no package.

[image: Showing yellow yraingle for the package]

Comment: Try to remove it and install again with nuget. Then copy paste the logs in the console in your question

Comment: It's not Working

Comment: But, there is an another dll called "Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll" in Nuget and it's working for me.